# Why are the number of vnodeids found in usageschema and show vnode inconsistent?

Tags: cnosdb

```
usage_schema ❯ select * from vnode_disk_storage where tenant = 'Tenant25Suborg23' order by time desc limit 20;
+-------------------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| time                          | database | node_id             | tenant           | vnode_id | value    |
+-------------------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| 2024-02-23T03:09:05.153940748 | demoset  | 1704972876971357965 | Tenant25Suborg23 | 78       | 0        |
| 2024-02-23T03:09:05.153940398 | demoset  | 1704972876971357965 | Tenant25Suborg23 | 69       | 0        |
| 2024-02-23T03:09:05.153940028 | demoset  | 1704972876971357965 | Tenant25Suborg23 | 66       | 13294250 |

public ❯ show vnode;
+----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| VNODE_ID | NODE_ID             | BUCKET_ID | REPLICATION_SET_ID | DATABASE_NAME | TENANT_NAME      | START_TIME          | END_TIME            | STATUS  |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 66       | 1704972876971357965 | 64        | 65                 | demoset       | Tenant25Suborg23 | 1705536000000000000 | 1708128000000000000 | Running |
| 78       | 1704972876971357965 | 76        | 77                 | demoset       | Tenant25Suborg23 | 1708128000000000000 | 1710720000000000000 | Running |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

cnosdb version 2.3.4.
When I checked the vnode_disk_storage table, I found that there were three vnodes under the tenant. But only two are seen through the show vnode command.
What happened to vnode 69？